# Trying to accelerate MILP solution

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling

I developed a mathematical model that contains several thousand of binary variables (in addition to several thousand continuous variables).

The binary variables model different things, say $X(i)$, $Y(j)$, $Z(k)$, ...  I made the observation, that if I fix the binaries of type $X(i)$ to their optimal value (even a subset of those) and optimize for the rest of the variables then I obtain the optimal solution to the problem very fast. Without this fixing, the solution time is very long.

The problem is that for a new setting of the problem, I don't know the optimal values $X(i)$.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could exploit the knowledge that if I get the optimal values for $X(i)$ the problem becomes easy?

I tried setting high branching priorities for the $X(i)$ variables but this doesn't really help. Optimizing only for $X(i)$ doesn't help either.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the *cut-and-solve*-method proposed by [Climer and Zhang 2006](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.artint.2006.02.005). The idea is roughly as follows

1. Somehow guess a good cut, that will limit the freedom of the $X$ variables.
2. After guessing such a cut, you solve to optimality the problem defined by the feasible set removed by the cut.
3. If this reduced problem has a feasible solution, it will give you a primal bound. Update best primal if necessary.
4. Then you add the cut to your original problem, and obtain a dual bound for this modified problem.
5. Now test if $(\text{best primal bound} - \text{dual bound})\leq 0$ (minimization case). If so, you have solved your problem to optimality. Otherwise go back to 1.

The method is described in Figure 4 of the linked paper. I have had good luck using this method for problems where the problem after reducing the wiggle room of the $X$-variables is significantly easier to solve, than the original full problem.

The idea is somewhat similar to local branching.

Answer (score 3):

First, knowing that fixing $X$ makes solution faster may not give you any leverage whatsoever. Consider a MIP model with binary variables $X$ and all other variables continuous. If you fix $X$ at optimal values, the rest is an LP that solves quickly. That fact tells you nothing about *how* to fix the values of $X.$

Second, high branching priorities for $X$ is a sound thing to try. The fact that it didn't help means either (a) the solver is already prioritizing branching on $X$, (b) branching on $X$ does not immediately result in much pruning of nodes or (c) both.

Hypothetically there might be a way to combine prioritization of $X$ with something else, but that would be model-specific, so not something easily suggested with what we have to go on.

Comment: I was expecting to see "Benders" in your answer. :)  Any reason not to recommend it here?

Comment: Oh, that is great. Let's try Benders decomposition.

Comment: @RobPratt Are you thinking Benders with a MIP subproblem ($X$ in the master; $Y$, $Z$ etc. in the subproblem)? [Also, I gave Benders a couple of days off, since he's been working so hard lately. :-)]

Comment: Yes, $X$ in master because fixing it makes the problem easy.  (Also, did you really give him time off, or did he cut?)

Comment: The reason I didn't recommend (generalized) Benders with a MIP subproblem is that the cuts you generate from a MIP subproblem tend not to be particularly tight (although, as with anything MIP-ish, I'm sure there are exceptions). So I'm not sure generalized Benders would lead to faster convergence of $X$ than just giving $X$ top branching priority would. (And puns like that are likely to earn you cutting remarks.)

Comment: :) Yes, hard to tell without seeing the full model.  Maybe we are lucky and the problem structure is such that integrality of $X$ automatically implies integrality of the other variables, as I saw in a recent project.  @Clement please update your question with more details of the model.

Comment: Did he <Benders> cut?  Benders decomposed. https://happyhappybirthday.net/en/age/jacques-f-benders-person_yxfqyyy

Comment: Hi Rob! I was away for a few weeks not working on anything, thus the late reply. The variables X(i,j) model tasks i on machines j  [X(i,j)=1 if i on j is performed, 0 otherwise], variables Z(i,j,i1,j1) model precedence relations among these tasks (if task i1 on machine j1 precedes task i2 on machine j2 then Z(i1,j1,i2,j2) = 1 else 0. There is no way that integrality of X implies integrality of Z.  It is advantageous to first branch on variables X. Cplex supports only continuous subproblems. So, the attempt to use Benders has failed.